# How can I automatically apply dark and light themes using the Lightning Email Template Builder in Salesforce based on the user's system preferences?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, email-templates

To meet the requirement, I aim to dynamically adjust the dark and light mode theme of the email template based on the user's system preferences after sending the email. This functionality will enhance the user experience by automatically adapting to their preferred theme settings.

How to achieve this functionality using Salesforce?

I tried using the LWC component but faced an issue while merging custom fields in that email template